# Java concurrency: resettable enabled/disabled wait condition

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I want to let a thread sleep until a certain condition becomes off. Basically, I need three operations:

- `enable()`: enable sleeping mode (do nothing if already enabled)
- `disable()`: disable sleeping mode (do nothing if already disabled)
- `await()`: wait until sleeping mode becomes disabled (or return immediately if the sleeping mode was already disabled) or the thread becomes interrupted (`InterruptedException` is thrown)

With this, thread `A` calls `enable()`. Now thread `B` calls `await()` and goes to sleep until thread `A` (or another one) calls `disable()`. This cycle can be repeated.

I know this can be quite easily done with `wait()` and `notify()`, but I am wondering if JDK8 has such functionality built-in?

The closest I could find is was a `CountdownLatch(1)`, unfortunately the implementation is not resettable.

Basically, I just want to call `enable()`/`disable()` and `await()`, while all concurrency concepts are abstracted in the implementation (though `await()` should throw `InterruptedException`, which is unavoidable).

Comment: `Lock` should work, eg `ReentrantLock`.

Comment: @daniu With `Lock`, I believe I still have to model the wait condition myself. All a `Lock` does is providing a critical section to manipulate that wait condition and inform waiting parties safely, as far as I know. Basically, I just want to call `enable()`/`disable()` and `await()`, while all concurrency concepts are abstracted in the implementation (though `await()` should throw `InterruptedException`, which is unavoidable).

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Condition` :

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class Switch {
    private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private final Condition on = lock.newCondition();
    private final Condition off = lock.newCondition();
    private volatile boolean state = true; 

    public void enable() {
        try {
            lock.lock();
            state = true;
            on.signalAll();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void disable() {
        try {
            lock.lock();
            state = false;
            off.signalAll();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void await() {
        try {
            lock.lock();
            while(!state) {
                try {
                    off.await();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("waiting interrupted.");
                }
            }
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would upvote this as well, but this has a few problems. First, it's better to let `await()` just throw the `InterruptedException`. There is no need to translate to a `RuntimeException`. If you still decide to do that however, you have to reset the interrupted flag before throwing the `RuntimeException`. Second, you are signaling the `on` lock, but nobody is ever waiting on that. You can remove that. Third, there is no need to make `state` volatile, as it is already guarded by the memory barrier set by the lock.

Comment: Also, another downside of this implementation is that for every `await()` call, a lock must be acquired. Your other answer (`Semaphore` based) and my answer do not suffer from that. Both have some kind of fail-fast path, which relies on `volatile` visibility. This is usually a bit faster than acquiring a lock each time.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible implementation of `Switch`:

```
public class Switch {
    private final AtomicBoolean state = new AtomicBoolean();

    public void enable() {
        state.set(true);
    }

    public void disable() {
        if (state.compareAndSet(true, false)) {
            synchronized (state) {
                state.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }

    public void await() throws InterruptedException {
        if (state.get()) {
            synchronized (state) {
                while (state.get()) {
                    state.wait();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
enable(): enable sleeping mode (do nothing if already enabled)
disable(): disable sleeping mode (do nothing if already disabled)
```

`do nothing if already enabled (disabled)` is a bad design, which can lead to subtle bugs which are hard to reproduce and discover. For example, let sleeping mode is disabled, and one thread calls `disable()` and the other calls `enable()`. Depending on which call is made first, the mode will stay enabled or disabled forever. To make execution more deterministic, enabling and disabling must be counted, and the final state will be determined (disabled).

Instead, your threads should exchange *tokens* which do not mask each other. Besides `CountdownLatch`, (which effectively is a counter of prohibitions), JDK has `CyclicBarrier` and `Phaser`, which are resettable counters of prohibitions, and `Semaphore`, which is a counter of permissions.

UPDT
this implementation may work (I did not tested it):

```
Phaser p = new Phaser(1);

public void await() {
    p.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();
}

public void enable() {
    p.register();
}

public void disable() {
    p.arriveAndDeregister();
}
```

N sequential calls to `enable()` require the same number of `disable()` to pass the awaiting thread.

Comment: Could you show how you would implement what @OneLastSpark asks with one of the three classes you mention ? (`CyclicBarrier`, `Phaser` or `Semaphor`) ? I tried to come up to something with one of these, but there was always a use case that would not work with these (in particular during the switch off of the sleeping mode when the thread B was not waiting already)

Comment: In the question : until thread A (*or another one*) calls `disable()`. But `arriveAndDeregister()` (`disable()`) must be called by the thread that called `register()` (`enable()`)

Comment: Also, if two different threads calls the `enable()` method both will have to call the `disable()` method for the await to end. Which implies that calling the `enable()` method should be done in a `try` and the `disable()` method in the `finally` block otherwise the switch will be blocked longer than intended (potentially until jvm stops).

Comment: I understand you concerns and remark regarding passing a token, but this is not really applicable to my question. I have no token to pass, and I never ever want `enable()` or `disable()` to block. Thierry's concerns are spot on.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Semaphor` too :

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class Switch {

    private Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1);

    public void enable() {
        synchronized(this) {
            semaphore.drainPermits(); // 0
            semaphore.reducePermits(1); // -1 or 0
        }
    }

    public void disable() {
        semaphore.release(2); // 1 or 2
    }

    public void await() throws InterruptedException {
        semaphore.acquire();
        semaphore.release();
    }


}
```

Comment: This comes closest to that I wanted. I was hoping such `Switch` implementation already existed in the `concurrent` package.

Comment: As an afterthought, this solution is not correct. There is a small chance that `enable()` will be called between the two operations in `await()`. In that case, `enable()` will be ignored. I think it can be solved by adding a spin wait loop in `enable()`: `while(semaphore.drainPermits() == 0) { Thread.yield(); }`.

Comment: In JDK9, we can do `Thread.onSpinWait()` instead of `Thread.yield()`.

Comment: indeed. The issue with `Thread.yield` is that if you call `enable()` while the sleep mode is already enabled, the method won't return. I think we can avoid the issue by incrementing the number of permits for enable / disable action to 2. (see update) (but we need to prevent 2 simultaneous calls to `enable` to avoid going down to -2)